# R: Data import numbers in Quotationsmarks + comma seperated

Tags: r, csv, import

How to import a csv-file, if

```
1)  sep = ","
2a) numbers are identified by ""
2b) dec = ","
```

Data Example (csv)

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,f,"1,20"
0,m,"1,01"
1,m,"1,00"
```

Desired output (in R, e.g. as dataframe)

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    f 1.20
2    0    m 1.01
3    1    f 1.00
```

I tried various versions of read.csv2, read.csv, fread - and get for example the error message "Too many columns for number of headers".

Does anyone know a trick?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: That sounds like a problem in the csv file itself. As the error states it has at least one line with more columns than headers. You could try open it in microsoft excel or similar to check if it has correct rectangular layout.

Comment: It opens fine in excel - except that the csv has more rows than a single excel sheet provides. Problem: if "" is ignored the comma separated results  of the rows = 4 columns, while the header prvides comma separated only three column headers!

Comment: Wow that is a big CSV ;) I guess that renders my suggestion (to check in Excel if it is rectangular) invalid - you probably cannot check for superfluous columns in each row manually.

Comment: Another idea: try to extract the first 10 rows or so to a seperate file. If you can load that file your CSV is corrupted. If not your R code is wrong.

Comment: a3 <- read.table("table.CSV",quote="", sep=",", dec=",")    error message "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 23 elements";

Comment: a2 <- read.csv("table.CSV",quote="" )  results in error message: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: a <- read.csv2("table.CSV",quote="" )  resulst in a dataframe with correct number of rows but only 1 single (not splitted!) column.

Comment: did you try `quote="\""` : `read.table("table.CSV" quote="\"", sep=",", dec=",", header=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, but I get Error: unexpected symbol in "a4 <- read.table("table.CSV" quote".  I tried  quote="\' "  , quote=" \' " , quote="\\' ", and quote=" \" " (note: quotation marks ' and ")

Comment: sorry, missing a comma before `quote=..` . You could also try `data.table::fread` which is often fairly good at guessing the structure of the data.

Comment: I saw the missing comm - but thanks for mentioning it. Yes, i tried again a number of variation of fread(), particularly since it is a really big data set and fread is pretty fast. Alas I don't get the syntax right.

Comment: id just try `fread("table.CSV")` ps. are you able to share the data ?

Comment: `read.csv(file, dec = ",")` worked fine for me with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make up some fake data. First, let's take the data you posted:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,f,"1,20"
0,m,"1,01"
1,m,"1,00"
```

and save it as a csv file. I did this manually in Mac's text editor (copy and paste). I saved the file as "fake.csv". You can go ahead and do this yourself or you can download the one I created from a dropbox link (yes I know outside links are frowned upon but I've also provided an alternative to dropbox that will reproduce the example). Here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ia77b952m1k6kx/fake.csv?dl=0).

If you have an especially large dataset, perhaps you'll want to load it using `readr`, which handles large datasets very well. You'll note, however, when importing using `read_csv`, the `,` is removed from the string entirely and `read_delim(file, delim=",")` does the same.

```
data<-as.data.frame(read_csv("PATH/fake.csv"))
```

> ```
> Parsed with column specification:
> cols(
>   Col1 = col_integer(),
>   Col2 = col_character(),
>   Col3 = col_number()
> )
> ```

```
data
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    f  120 # no comma
2    0    m  101 #''      ''
3    1    m  100 #''      ''
```

One, perhaps clunky way, to get around that is to use the following code in pipe. The logic here is that all your numbers end with the final digit in the hundredth position.

```
data %>% 
   group_by('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3') %>% 
   mutate(Col3=str_replace(data$Col3, "\\d\\d$", gsub("^\\d", ".", data$Col3))) %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>% 
   select(1,2,3)

  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    f 1.20
2    0    m 1.01
3    1    m 1.00
```

As a function:

```
import_csv<-function(x) {

    library(readr)
    library(dplyr)

    data <-read_csv(x)

    data <-data %>% 
        group_by('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3') %>% 
        mutate(Col3=str_replace(data$Col3, "\\d\\d$", gsub("^\\d", ".", data$Col3))) %>% 
        as.data.frame() %>% 
        select(1,2,3)

    print(data)

}

import_csv("PATH/fake.csv")
```

> ```
> Parsed with column specification:
> cols(
>   Col1 = col_integer(),
>   Col2 = col_character(),
>   Col3 = col_number()
> )
> ```

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    f 1.20
2    0    m 1.01
3    1    m 1.00
```